# How to prevent click on parent in Angular/Ionic2?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have the list on which items when it's clicked I need to do some actions. Also I have sliding menu on those actions. When I slide it and click it also triggers the click on `ion-item-sliding. Is it possible somehow to prevent click when slid is open?

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let event of events" (click)="showModalInfo(event)">
    <ion-item>
        <h2>{{ event['Event type'] }}</h2>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options side="right">
        <button ion-button color="light" icon-left (click)="showDescription(event)">
            <ion-icon name="ios-more"></ion-icon>
            More
        </button>
    </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
(click)="$event.stopPropagation();showDescription($event)"
```